# UIPickerView different Background/title Colours of different sets of pickerLabel (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uicolor

I am trying to set specific background and title colouring to different parts of the same UIPickerView according to the actual row. That is, having 150 elements in the same UIPickerView I need to have different colouring to ease (or fasten) the search time of a specific element. However the only related article I could find was the following: https://makeapppie.com/tag/uipickerview-in-swift/.

For example rows 0-19 of black colour, rows 20-50 red.. etc..
And this is what I got to so far:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->NSAttributedString?{
    let titleData = PickerTeaArray[row]
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    let newSwiftColor = UIColor(red: 250, green: 200, blue: 101)
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:newSwiftColor])
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .left

    return myTitle
}
```

Later on in the code I am assigning different values to simple labels according to the row.

Could you please suggest of going about it?

Comment: Your code is fine other than adjusting the color based on the row. What is your actually question? What do you actually need help with?

Comment: How exactly can I assign the background colour depending on the row range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted needs only one adjustment. You need to vary the color based on the `row` parameter value. Based on what you stated in your question you can do something like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->NSAttributedString?{
    let titleData = PickerTeaArray[row]
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    let newSwiftColor: UIColor
    switch row {
        case 0...19:
            newSwiftColor = .black
        case 20...50:
            newSwiftColor = .red
        default:
            newSwiftColor = UIColor(red: 250.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 101.0/255.0)
    }

    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:newSwiftColor])
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .left

    return myTitle
}
```

Add and adjust the `case` statements as needed and return whatever colors you actually want.

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what I was looking for!